# Using mstrsplit to make a character matrix

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

I am trying to convert several comments into a matrix of characters so that I can extract numbers with the ultimate goal of building a character based neural network to identify amounts.
It seems that even though they are stored as characters which I can verify with strsplit the mstrsplit function from iotools wont put them in a matrix.

```
library("tm")
library("iotools")

sample1 <- "This is a number 2,000$ presented properly."
sample2 <- "This could be another representation $ 2,000."
sample3 <- "Often times there is 400 many $20 numbers 3.75$ in a single 1025.50 sentence."
sample4 <- "Frequently a data 21/02/2017 precedes a number 5 000 or follows it February 21, 2017."
sample5 <- "There are many 50 000 possible ways 20, 400$ that numbers can be presented."
sample6 <- "Creating an exhaustive list is probably impossible at 9:52 int he morning."
sample7 <- " use of different characters $ might be confusing."

text1 <- c(sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5, sample6, sample7)
text <- as.character(text1)
str(text)
characters <- strsplit(text, "")
text
characters 
matrixc <- mstrsplit(characters, sep=NA)
matrixc
matrixc[1,19]
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting Frank. Also I found a solution suing matrix(unlist()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative in matrix(unlist(()).

```
  text1 <- c(sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5, sample6, sample7)
  text2 <- as.character(text1)
  str(text2)
  char1 <- strsplit(text2, character(0))
  mat1 <- matrix(unlist(char1))
  mat1
```